# Is it possible create pagination to both sides in compose?

Tags: android, pagination, android-jetpack-compose

I have a question about compose paging data. I need to create a LazyColumn (for example) and fetch data to top of the list and to bottom (it depends of user scroll), all examples and tutorials about pagging to the bottom. May be someone have a possible solution or an idea how to do it?

Comment: It would be possible, you would just need to check whether `lazyColumnListState.firstVisibleItemIndex < firstVisibleItemIndex` and if so append more data to the start of your data source and if not append the data at the end (but not sure how efficient the top scroll would be, as I do believe all of the other elements would have to be reordered)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this solution a little bit later